# Digital signal "square" wave function with finite rise time

Tags: functions

Is there a built in function for a non-ideal square wave with finite rise and fall times to approximate digital signals?

I know this should be possible with a piece-wise function but I though Mathematica is so extensive there may be a built in function.

Comment: Can you give an example of that sort of square wave?

Comment: Welcome! I suggest the following:   
1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) and check the [faqs](http://goo.gl/kQNRaS)!   
3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Comment: @axk: depends on what you want to do with the waveform. For signal processing I would use a pure square wave feeding a 1st order filter. Everything is kept linear, so you can do either numerical simulation or Laplace calculations.

Comment: I was thinking having a function that I can use in a differential equasion with DSolve to solve for voltages and currents in a simple buck converter type switching power supply.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In absence of a specific example perhaps a clipped triangle wave would be of use?

```
Manipulate[
  Plot[Clip[c*TriangleWave[x]], {x, 0, 3}],
  {c, 1, 30}
]
```

[image]

Two more options using filtering, though not directly as a function.

[FIR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_impulse_response):

```
sq = Table[SquareWave[x], {x, 0, 4, 0.01}];

Manipulate[ListLinePlot @ LowpassFilter[sq, ω], {ω, 0.05, 0.5}]
```

[image]

[IIR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infinite_impulse_response):

```
Manipulate[
  ListLinePlot @ RecurrenceFilter[{{1, β}, {1}}, sq],
  {β, -0.90, -0.1}
]
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

[`SquareWave`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SquareWave.html) is a built-in function:

```
Plot[(1 + SquareWave[x]) /2, {x, 0, 3}, ExclusionsStyle -> Dotted]
```

[image]

For finite rise and fall times, you could try `FourierSinSeries` (change the parameters if you need):

```
mysquarewave[x_] := Evaluate[FourierSinSeries[SquareWave[x], x, 10,
  FourierParameters -> {1, 2 Pi}]];
Plot[(1 + mysquarewave[x]) /2, {x, 0, 3}]
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, but if we consider OP's "finite rise and fall times", that's apparently not what s/he wants. (But OP should really clarify...)

Comment: @J.M. I submitted my answer too early... Fixed it!

Comment: I dunno... Gibbs might or might not be a problem for the second one.